# Why isn't "earth" and "heaven" capitalized in most texts?

Tags: word-usage

And I'm talking about planet earth and the biblical heaven. Examples:

> [Her soul couldn't go to heaven.](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&tbm=bks&q=%22her%20soul%20couldn%27t%20go%20to%20heaven%22)
>
> [When the Bible talks about Noah, can we construe that Noah was the
>   only man on earth at that time?](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&tbm=bks&q=%22the%20only%20man%20on%20earth%22)

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think both forms could be used depending on the situation.

In regards to Heaven, Christians believe it is the proper name of a place and therefore it should be capitalized.  Atheists may consider it more of an abstract concept than a place and thus may not choose to capitalize it, though this is especially dependent on usage.

Regarding Earth, if you are referring to the proper name of the planet Earth you should be capitalizing it.  If you are referring to the actual dirt/land that something sits on you may reference it as earth.  I would argue that the above referenced sentence uses "earth" improperly, and that it should be capitalized in that context.

Comment: And the soul example is referring to the non-Christian heaven?

Comment: It could be presumed that the author is referring to the concept of a level of existence after death, as opposed to respecting the idea of it as a specific place with a proper name.  But there's no way to tell without context whether it was that or simply careless lack of capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

In this context I think "earth" and "heaven" are not places, but states of the human condition.

For example, on "earth", you may not be physically on Earth-- you may be in space!

Proper noun "Heaven" implies a specific place, but different religions may have different names for it or ideas about it, and may not think of it as a place at all. So instead, the lowercase "heaven" makes clear that we are speaking of a generic heaven-*like* afterlife, and not one religion's specific heaven.

I don't think either way would be grammatically wrong, though. I think you could make a case to uppercase them.